# How to configure the decimal inputs in Better Exposed Filter module in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-9

I have a problem with using Better exposed filter 6.0.3 in the view to filter the number values with decimal.  In range minimum, range maximum and Step it shows like it allows certain decimal digits to give input. But it is not allowing to give input decimal inputs in all the three fields.

Is there a way to configure it to allow decimal values?

[image]